# Java issue setting serialVersionUID

Tags: java, networking, serialization

I am currently trying to write a multiplayer space-invaders-like game where the client runs on a computer and the server on an android device. For that reason I need to transmit the position of all the objects via network, I'm using serialization.
At first I had this class for the game data, which was not thread-safe, but could be serialized and deserialized just fine:

```
public class gamestate implements Serializable{

  public ship firstplayer;
  public ship secondplayer;
  public ship[] enemies;

}
```

As I said, that was not thread-safe, so I tried adding an empty method which would force Java to re-fetch the object before proceeding:

```
synchronized void v(){}
```

This is where the problems began. Even though I have exactly the same code on PC and phone, the generated serialVersionUIDs did not match, so I tried setting them myself.

```
  static final long serialVersionUID = 1000L;
```

This had the following result:

```
ru.black.ksserver.gamestate; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1000, local class serialVersionUID = -4828470651897483247
```

It seems like setting it on android worked perfectly fine while setting it on PC did not. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you sure that you use new class with `serialVersionUUID` in PC and not the old one without it?

Comment: Did you consider setting it to -4828470651897483247? As specifically mentioned in the error message?

Comment: I tried it and it works, however every time I change anything in the class I have to set the new ID on the other end. It's a solution for now but I hope whatever is broken will work again soon.

Comment: That only means that you should use the same .class file, generated from the same .java file, at both ends. If you're trying to maintain two parallel copies of the same class you are doomed to failure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use an explicit `serialVersionUID` in a class, you need to:

- use the same value for `serialVersionUID` in all copies of the class
- make sure that you deal with any differences what is included in the serialization.

If you don't use an explicit `serialVersionUID` in a class, then the versions of the classes at both ends must have the same default serial version.   The [Object Serialization spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#4100) explains how the default serial version is computed.

---

> It seems like setting it on android worked perfectly fine while setting it on PC did not.

Actually, it looks to me like you are trying to read an instance that was serialized with `serialVersionUID` 1000 in a class that doesn't have an explicit `serialVersionUID` variable.  That won't work.

Did you actually change the class to add the explicit `serialVersionUID` variable on the PC side?   It looks like you didn't .....

Comment: I actually uploaded the .java file to google drive and downloaded it on pc to make sure I got no differences and it only registered the UID on android.

Comment: Erm do you mean the ".class" file?  And if you do mean the ".java" file, did you remember to compile it, rebuild the JAR, etcetera.  The fact that you are getting that message is incontravertable evidence that UID 1000 is *not* being used in the local class when deserializing.

Answer (score -1):

I (kinda) solved it and its a bug. If I run my program using the latest JDk it completely ignores this field, it only does what it's supposed to when using a older JDK. Did they change something in the latest update? Or maybe my installation is just broken...

Comment: Rubbish. Java does not completely ignore this field, in any version. You fixed something else, or completely redeployed you application to all nodes.

Comment: then my installation is broken because i got different results for the same cmd call. i packed it to a jar, tried it out 5 times with each version and it doesnt work with the new one but with the old.